# Change activities/application menu bar in linux with java/javafx

Tags: java, linux, ubuntu, javafx, debian

I'm trying and searching everywhere but I can't find how to change this text (the one in the red box):

[image]

I have this problem in both Ubuntu 18.4 and Debian 9

Comment: You should show the relevant code and present it as text (and not in a cropped picture).

Answer (score -1):

You cannot. However, you could rename your main class and move it into a different package with a simpler name.

You could also try removing the `package` directive to use the default package.